# How to do find out what data the report uses?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Our team manages a large number of reports and we are looking to do some clean up. Due to the frequent shuffle of positions, some reports might been touched by 10+ persons.

We are upgrading to SSRS 2012, One of our daily report needs to be rewritten. It is buggy and slow. It has 7 different sub reports. Within each of them, we uses 4-5 ad-hoc query and 1-2 store producers. With in the each SP, there are 6-7 functions and 2-3 view used.

Some functions and views are used by lots of different reports and no much documentation is left on who uses them.

We are also looking to set up internal schema with in a table to avoid the excess use of functions.

**Is there a way to map what the report uses? Like some way to automatically generate tree diagram. Like from the report name to dataset to sp to views+functions, etc**

So that when I am rewriting this thing I don't want to murder someone.....

Thank you for any help.
As I am writing this, I realized that how difficult the task will be.....

Comment: This is nearly an impossible task to do automatically. Especially given the 4-5 ad hoc queries.

Comment: If your reports use procedures, you could view the procedure's dependencies. If you are going to refactor how your team approaches reports, I would suggest using procedures for your data this time around.

Comment: I have used this: http://bretstateham.com/extracting-ssrs-report-rdl-xml-from-the-reportserver-database/  in the past to look inside reports. Getting SQL object dependencies (views/functions in procs, etc) would be another level, though.

Comment: In vs you can view code. If you view code on all your reports and copy it to word you can atleast use the ctrl + F to find certain procs that are used.